# Insert values from multiple pandas dataframes with unsorted index to existing column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that creates several pandas dataframes with unsorted indexes. I want to add the values from these dataframes to an existing column in another dataframe based on index.

To get what i mean:

```
# original dataframe
df_original = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(8), 'b':range(8)})
df_original['c'] = np.nan

   a  b   c
0  0  0 NaN
1  1  1 NaN
2  2  2 NaN
3  3  3 NaN
4  4  4 NaN
5  5  5 NaN
6  6  6 NaN
7  7  7 NaN
```

My function returns dataframes one by one with unsorted index:

```
# first df that is returned
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1,8,2), data=range(4), columns=['c'])

   c
1  0
3  1
5  2
7  3

# second df that is returned
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,8,2), data=range(4), columns=['c'])

   c
0  0
2  1
4  2
6  3
```

I would like to add the c-column from these two dataframes to the c-column in the original dataframe´s c-column by index so i end up with:

```
# original dataframe in the end
    a   b   c
0   0   0   0
1   1   1   0
2   2   2   1
3   3   3   1
4   4   4   2
5   5   5   2
6   6   6   3
7   7   7   3
```

How could I do this efficiently? My real original dataframe contains about 100k rows and the function returns around 100 values each time it´s called. In the end there will be no `np.nan` in the c-column.

I am currently looping each new dataframe in the end of the function and use `df_original.set_value()` to change the values in the original dataframe. There must be a better way?

I was also thinking about doing `df_temp = pd.concat((df1, df2...), axis=0)` with all the new dataframes and then finish with `pd.concat((df_original, df_temp), axis=1)`. How would you do this?

Comment: In my opinion your solution with double concat is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion double `concat` solution is nice.

Another alternative is use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df_temp = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df = df_original.join(df_temp)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  0
2  2  2  1
3  3  3  1
4  4  4  2
5  5  5  2
6  6  6  3
7  7  7  3
```

Comment: The double concat solution crossed my mind while writing the question. Have not tried it yet though. I'll do it later and accept the answer then!

Answer (score 2):

A simple assignment would be enough to do that i.e

```
df_original['c'] = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Output :

```
   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  0
2  2  2  1
3  3  3  1
4  4  4  2
5  5  5  2
6  6  6  3
7  7  7  3
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but I must say I am a bit surprised it worked. With that I mean I am surprised that this `df_original['c'] = pd.concat([df1,df2])` yields the same result as `df_original['c'] = pd.concat([df2,df1])` while `pd.concat([df2,df1])` and `pd.concat([df1,df2])` aren't sorted the same. So if I get it right, `=` work as a join on index?

Comment: While assigning, pandas look for matching index and then assign the data. So you dont need join for that.